# What is the difference between two types of list additions in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm adding the list with itself in 2 ways. In output the memory location of updated list sometimes matches with parent list and sometimes not.
May I know the explanation of this?

In 1st case I checked with + operator and assigned result to list reference.
But in second case I used += operator.

1st case:

```
  x=[1,2,3]
  print(x, id(x))
  x+=x
  print(x, id(x))
```

output:

```
  [1, 2, 3] 88777032
  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] 88777032
```

2nd case:

```
  y=[1,2,3]
  print(y, id(y))
  y=y+y
  print(y, id(y))
```

output:

```
  [1, 2, 3] 88297352
  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] 88776904
```

Answer (score 1):

1st case:
`x += x` just extends existing x by adding x

2nd case:
`y = y+y` creates a new list by concatenating y two times (y and y) and then assigns the result to newly created object y